# How to detect that username already use in the database

Tags: php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Add"]))    
{

$name=$_POST["Emp_Username"];
$pass=$_POST["Emp_Password"];
$fname=$_POST["Emp_Fname"];
$lname=$_POST["Emp_Lname"];
$hph=$_POST["ContactNo_Home"];
$hp=$_POST["ContactNo_HP"];
$mail=$_POST["Emp_Email"];
$add=$_POST["Emp_Address"];
$age=$_POST["Emp_Age"];
$pos=$_POST["Position"];
$dept=$_POST["Dept_ID"];

mysql_query("
    insert into employee(Dept_ID, Emp_Address, Emp_Age, 
    Position, >Emp_Username, Emp_Password, Emp_Fname, Emp_Lname, 
    ContactNo_Home, ContactNo_HP, Emp_Email) 
    >values('$dept','$add','$age','$pos','$name','$pass','$fname',
    '$lname','$hph','$hp','$mail'>)
   ");

?>    

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Record saved.");    
</script> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Use `UNIQUE` constraint on the username column in DB, in that case, insert with same username will fail (return an error). Then check for errors upon insert query.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611044/check-if-username-already-exists-in-database-mysql-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique key on username field, then detect error no 1062:

```
if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    print 'username taken!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple SELECT query should suffice:

```
SELECT COUNT(employee.Emp_Username) AS num 
FROM employee 
WHERE Emp_Username = 'USERNAME';
```

Comment: Without a unique constraint at DB level, this is a race condition

Comment: I know. But I based my answer on the assumption that the database is correctly designed. OP asked how to detect if the username is already detected. He didn't ask how to prevent duplicate usernames.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you,

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from employee where Emp_Username=$name");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row>0){
        echo 'user exist';
    }else{
        echo 'User not exist';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should validate field "user" with ajax before submit the form

```
$name = $_POST["Emp_Username"];
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Emp_Username='$name'");
$name_exist = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if($username_exist) {
    echo 'busy';
}else{
    echo 'free';
}
```

Comment: Without a unique constraint at DB level, this is a race condition.

Comment: Two connections ask for a given username simultaneous , both get the answer 'name free' - both will register the name in the assumption it unique - without a unique constraint both will succeed.